# is there any simple code for beginners where i can experiment diff kernels used in gaussian process example in scikit learn to know their functions?

Tags: scikit-learn, kernel, gaussian

actually i want to understand the kernels used in scikit learn gaussian example but i have zero knowledge about how those kernel behaves and when to use which and i also not getting any sample basic template code where i can use those kernel one by one and understand.The partial code is given below:

```
X, y = load_mauna_loa_atmospheric_co2()
```

Kernel with parameters given in GPML book

```
k1 = 66.0**2 * RBF(length_scale=67.0)  # long term smooth rising trend
k2 = 2.4**2 * RBF(length_scale=90.0) \
    * ExpSineSquared(length_scale=1.3, periodicity=1.0)  # seasonal component
# medium term irregularity
k3 = 0.66**2 \
    * RationalQuadratic(length_scale=1.2, alpha=0.78)
k4 = 0.18**2 * RBF(length_scale=0.134) \
    + WhiteKernel(noise_level=0.19**2)  # noise terms
kernel_gpml = k1 + k2 + k3 + k4

gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel_gpml, alpha=0,
                              optimizer=None, normalize_y=True)
gp.fit(X, y)

print("GPML kernel: %s" % gp.kernel_)
print("Log-marginal-likelihood: %.3f"
      % gp.log_marginal_likelihood(gp.kernel_.theta))

# Kernel with optimized parameters
k1 = 50.0**2 * RBF(length_scale=50.0)  # long term smooth rising trend
k2 = 2.0**2 * RBF(length_scale=100.0) \
    * ExpSineSquared(length_scale=1.0, periodicity=1.0,
                     periodicity_bounds="fixed")  # seasonal component
# medium term irregularities
k3 = 0.5**2 * RationalQuadratic(length_scale=1.0, alpha=1.0)
k4 = 0.1**2 * RBF(length_scale=0.1) \
    + WhiteKernel(noise_level=0.1**2,
                  noise_level_bounds=(1e-3, np.inf))  # noise terms
kernel = k1 + k2 + k3 + k4

gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, alpha=0,
                              normalize_y=True)
gp.fit(X, y)

print("\nLearned kernel: %s" % gp.kernel_)
print("Log-marginal-likelihood: %.3f"
      % gp.log_marginal_likelihood(gp.kernel_.theta))

X_ = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max() + 30, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]
y_pred, y_std = gp.predict(X_, return_std=True)

# Illustration
plt.scatter(X, y, c='k')
plt.plot(X_, y_pred)
plt.fill_between(X_[:, 0], y_pred - y_std, y_pred + y_std,
                 alpha=0.5, color='k')
plt.xlim(X_.min(), X_.max())
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel(r"CO$_2$ in ppm")
plt.title(r"Atmospheric CO$_2$ concentration at Mauna Loa")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

All the details are in the [book](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/) by Rasmussen and Williams. The example you show is in Chapter 5 along with a detailed explanation of all the kernels used. They also show many examples of covariance functions and corresponding random functions.

I am not aware of a code to simply visualise various kernels but one can visualise the popular squared exponential function, which appears multiple times in the Mauna Loa example with different length scales, as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def k_se(r,l):
    return np.exp(-r*r/(2*l*l)) 

r = np.arange(0.1,4,0.01)
plt.figure()
for ll in l:
    plt.plot(r,k_se(r,ll),label='length='+str(np.round(ll,1)))
    plt.xlabel('r')
    plt.ylabel('Covariance k(r)')
plt.legend(frameon=False)
```

Different kernels for different length scales look like: 
[image]

However what's more interesting is drawing random functions from a gaussian process that has given covariance function. The following code is not meant for efficiency or speed but to make it easy to visualise these random functions.

```
def k_se_p(x1, x2, l):
    return np.exp(-((x1-x2)*(x1-x2))/(2*l*l))

def gm(x,l):
    return [[k_se_p(i,j,l) for j in x] for i in x]

x = np.arange(0.1,8,0.01)
```

It is instructive to first draw functions from the same length scale:

```
plt.figure() 
for i in range(5):
    ys = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(len(x)), gm(x,l[0]))
    if i==0:
        plt.plot(x,ys,color='blue',label='length='+str(np.round(l[0],1)))
    else:
        plt.plot(x,ys,color='blue')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('f(x)') 
plt.legend(frameon=False)
```

Which gives a not very smooth functions:

[image]

A larger length scale gives smoother functions:

```
plt.figure() 
for i in range(5):
    ys = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(len(x)), gm(x,l[-1]))
    if i==0:
        plt.plot(x,ys,color='magenta',label='length='+str(np.round(l[-1],1)))
    else:
        plt.plot(x,ys,color='magenta')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.legend(frameon=False)
```

[image]

Finally we can draw one function from each length scale and plot them together:

```
plt.figure() 
for ll in l:
    ys = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(len(x)), gm(x,ll))
    plt.plot(x,ys,label='length='+str(np.round(ll,1)))
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('f(x)') 
plt.legend(frameon=False)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I 've opened that book but do not understand the math stuffs behind gaussian process , Do you have any suggestions from where I can get the intuition about what gaussian really is and why I need to use kernel? Suggest me like I am a grade 12 student.

Comment: You are correct the GP book is at a graduate level. Teaching GP is not really something I know a lot about but I can suggest two ways of going about to understand them. One is to familiarise yourself with the prerequisites of that book such as calculus, linear algebra and probability theory. The other more informal way is to take an example from scikit-learn like this one: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpr_noisy.html and get an operational understanding of GP. You have the explanation of different length scales from my answer above to assist you too.

Comment: I checked these but I think I need something from elementary level because of not having any kind of foundation at all. Thanks btw