# Calculate Gamma parameter for scikit-learn RBF Kernel to get Gaussian Kernel

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian

When using the [RBF Kernel](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.rbf_kernel.html) from scikit-learn the [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html#rbf-kernel) states that when setting `gamma` to sigma negative square the kernel becomes a gaussian kernel of variance sigma squared. Here is the quote:

> [image]

**Where do I get the value for Sigma?

Is it the standard deviation of something?

Is Sigma calculated from the two input vectors xi and xj or do I need two whole sets of data?

Is the calculated value for sigma then really only raised to the power of -2?**

Here is my current Python code for the problem:

```
def gaussian_kernel(x_i, x_j):

    # if gamma = sigma negative square then the kernel is known as the
    # Gaussian kernel of variance sigma square
    sigma = 0 #???
    gamma = sigma**-2 # <- is this even correct?
    kernel_result = rbf_kernel(x_i, x_j, gamma)

    return kernel_result
```

Comment: Gamma / Sigma is a hyperparameter - there isn't "one way" to calculate it. You need to decide it's value depending on how you model the problem and your data.
Some useful links:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125820/optimal-sigma-for-the-rbf-kernel
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391151/are-high-values-for-c-or-gamma-problematic-when-using-an-rbf-kernel-svm

Comment: For a gaussian process the standard deviation can be interpreted as the length scale which defines how quickly the random functions change. There are some examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772051/is-there-any-simple-code-for-beginners-where-i-can-experiment-diff-kernels-used